# Typescript - subscription inside iteration

Tags: arrays, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, observable

I am trying to call the "getData" API over and over for each value in the "myArray" variable. Each time it gets new data from the "getData" call, I am trying to push the result to an array so I can manipulate the values in the "destinationArray" section of code. However, since typescript is not async, it gets to the "destinationArray" code before it's finished in the .subscribe / before it's finished iterating.

**I've already tried fixing this with `await waitUntil(() => done==true, { timeout: 10015 });`**
but I keep getting randomly appearing messages in the console saying `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Timed out after waiting for 10015 ms`. The naive answer is to just increase the timeout to infinity, but the actual API call itself does not take 10 seconds, it takes about 1 second (if even that long). **How can I make it wait until it's finished iterating / subscribing before it moves onto the "destionationArray" section at the bottom, without seeing that timeout error message in the console?**

```
let dataFromAPIcall: any[] = []
let myArray: any[] = ["hello","world"]
for(let i = 0; i< myArray.length; i++) {    
    this.GetDataSubScription = this.myService.getData(myArray[i]).pipe( takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) ).subscribe(data => {
        dataFromAPIcall.push(data)
        if(i+1 == myArray.length) {
            done = true
        }
    });
}

await waitUntil(() => done==true, { timeout: 10015 });
                    
let destinationArray: any[] = [];
for(let i = 0; i < dataFromAPIcall.length; i++) {
    destinationArray[i] = [dataFromAPIcall[i].something1, dataFromAPIcall[i].something2]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` your api calls and handle all responses in a reactive way, without using imperative state variables:

> After all observables emit, emit values as an array

```
// creating an array of observables. The requests are not fired yet.
const requests = myArray.map(i => this.myService.getData(i));
const destinationArray: any[] = [];

// passing the request array to the zip function.
// this will actual initiate the requests and emit when ALL
// requests are done
zip(...requests).pipe(
  tap(responses => {
      // maping responses to destinationArray
      destinationArray = responses.map(dataFromAPIcall => [dataFromAPIcall.something1, dataFromAPIcall.something2])
  }),
  tap(_ => {
    // continue here
  })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: nice approach!!

Comment: 2 questions... 1. would any code after the .subscribe be executed *only* after all requests have completed in the array? 2. If I wanted to store the responses in the destination array, would I just add a "destinationArray =" just before "responses.map(...)"?

Comment: The code after subscribe is executed immediately. I have updated my anwser. The destinationArray is updated now and i left a comment where you can execute your code.